Structural plank subfloor, underlayment questions
I'm remodeling my 1963 rancher and I'm replacing the flooring in the kitchen/living area which is all one space after a wall removal. It has 1*6 diagonal structural planks as the subfloor. They are NOT tongue and groove. There was a layer of 3/4 in partical board on top of that which I have removed. First question: Do I need a layer of felt between the subfloor and underlayment? 2nd question: How thick of an underlayment do I need? I was considering 1/2 in plywood for thickness purposes, but wondering if I should be going with 5/8 or even 3/4? Plywood or OSB? Tongue and groove or not? Forewarning - there will be lots of followup questions. 

Type of finish flooring expected to use.  63 planks are probably 3/4 inch or better, so unless ceramic tiles are to be used, it might be good enough for most flooring, if solid and flat.  Tiles do not like any movement(bounce) of the sub floor.  The wall removal might be a bigger question/problem, if it was a load bearing wall.  Please tell us it was not in the centre of the house and/or you had an engineer design the removal.

What underlayment you need is dependant on what the finished floor is going to be.  Add that info into your question.

I would like to use ceramic tile. The plank subfloor is a full 3/4". It definitely needs an underlayment layer - it's not very stable.

And yes, the wall removed was a load bearing wall from the center of the house. Why does that matter?

Load bearing walls hold up what is above them.  I am hoping you had a structural engineer design a replacement for that wall, or else the flooring will not matter.

Yes, the removed wall and supporting beam were engineer designed.

You already have a subfloor—the planks.  What you put on top depends what kind of underlay you intend—you using Ditra? Cement board?  Something else?.  Never heard of using felt with tile though.  What's your joist spacing?

Yes, the planks are the subfloor. Again, I'm trying to figure out what kind of underlayment I need. 1/2"? 5/8"? 3/4"? Tongue and groove? Plywood or OSB?

And yes, on top of the underlayment layer will be Ditra and tile.

@DMoore Are you out there? Can I DM you?
